# What's the difference of "-a" and "-i" between ''docker create" and "docker start"

Tags: docker, concept

The regular workflow of docker is: first `docker create`, then `docker start`. What make me confused are:

**Question 1**

`docker create` has an option `-a` to specify which of `stdin`, `stdout`, `stderr` are attached to the container. `docker start` also has the same option.

What's the difference? If `docker create` specified `-a stderr` only, can `docker start` specify `-a stdout` in addition?

**Question 2**

`docker create` has an option `-i`. `docker start` also has the same option.

What's the difference? If `docker create` doesn't specified `-i`, can `docker start` specify `-i`?